# TCP/IP Socket is not reading data from machine when running as Windows Service in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp, windows-services

I have a simple TCP/IP program to read data from a machine and write it into text file.  I want to run it as Windows Service so that data gets written into text file continuously with out any intervention.  Now when I try to run the program under debug mode of Visual Studio, it is reading the data from the machine and saving into text file, but as soon as I add it as Windows Service and try to start the service, it is giving following error message..

```
windows service could not start the service on the local computer

error:1053 The service did not respond to the start or the control request in a timely  fashion
```

Here is my main applications code..

```
static void Main()
    {

        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new Service1() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

    }
```

Here is my code to communicate to the machine using TCP/IP and read/write data into text file..

```
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        ipaddress = "";
        int port = int.Parse("");
        textfileSaveLocation = "";

        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        string stringData;

        IPAddress ipadd = IPAddress.Parse(ipaddress);
        IPEndPoint ipend = new IPEndPoint(ipadd, port);
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sock.NoDelay = false;
        try
        {
            sock.Connect(ipend);

        }
        catch (Exception dfg)
        {    
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            buf = String.Format("SMDR", "PCCSMDR");
            bBuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(buf);
            sock.Send(bBuf);

            while (true)
            {
                data = new byte[1024];
                int recv = sock.Receive(data);
                stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);

                string df = "";
                try
                {
                    FileStream dr = new FileStream(textfileSaveLocation, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                    StreamReader fg = new StreamReader(dr);
                    df = fg.ReadToEnd();
                    fg.Dispose();
                    dr.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception dfjdfs)
                {
                }

                try
                {
                    FileStream cd = new FileStream(textfileSaveLocation, FileMode.Create);
                    StreamWriter cdf = new StreamWriter(cd);
                    cdf.WriteLine(df);
                    cdf.WriteLine(stringData);
                    cdf.Dispose();
                    cd.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception hgy)
                {
                }
            }
            sock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sock.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception DFGFD)
        {
        }
    }
```

My only aim with this program is to run it as Windows Service through installer and start the service.  Once the service is started, it should read the data from the given ip and port of the machine and save it into text file.  Also I need this service to continuously monitor for the data from the machine and once new data comes to the machine, it should read and write into the text file.

Do I need to implement Multi-threading in the program?

Comment: Well, swallowing exceptions is not going to make debugging easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system expects the `OnStart` method to return in a timely fashion (~30 seconds), so long-running tasks like monitoring for data need to be moved to another thread.  This can be as simple as:

```
private System.Threading.Thread _thread;
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _thread = new Thread(DoWork);
    _thread.Start();
}

private void DoWork()
{
    // create and monitor socket here...
}
```

Note that while your `while (true)` loop is sufficient to keep the thread running, it makes it difficult to stop it when the service stops.  For this, I use a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like so.

```
using System.Threading;
private ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

private void DoWork()
{
    // initialize socket and file

    // thread loop
    while (!_shutdownEvent.Wait(0))
    {
        // read socket, write to file
    }

    // close socket and file
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    _shutdownEvent.Set();
    _thread.Join();  // wait for thread to stop
}
```

Comment: If need to debug the service, call `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` inside `Main` or `OnStart`.  When you start the service, you should be prompted to start a normal debug session from there.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion and tested it on debug mode.On debug mode it was working file but as soon as i made a setup file for installation using visual studio and installed and started from there,no data is getting dumped into text file..Do i need to add these line int recv = sock.Receive(data);
                stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv); before the while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0)) loop to make it running as Windows service live mode.

Comment: The location of that code shouldn't matter between debug or live mode.  When you run in live mode, is your working directory where you think it is?  Have you tried debugging the service using my suggestion above?

Comment: yes sir the working directory is there only.Di i need to add int recv = sock.Receive(data); stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv); before  (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0)) loop to make it running as Windows service live mode

Comment: Again, the location of those lines shouldn't make a difference between debug and live.  When you start the service, does it run and stay running, i.e., can you see it in Task Manager?

Comment: i am testing for debug like this in my main program #if DEBUG

            Service1 myservice = new Service1();
            myservice.OnDebug();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

#else
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
   { 
    new Service1() 
   };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45435/discussion-between-matt-davis-and-adi)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Matt's answer.

Also, In general , it is good to add an option to debug your service, here is an example:

```
     protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {         
                bool launchDebugger = false;
                if (args.Count() > 0)
                {
                    launchDebugger = args[0].ToLower() == "debug";
                }


                if (launchDebugger)
                {                   
                   Debugger.Launch();
                }    
}
```

When you run the service with an argument: "debug", it will trigger a fake exception,
allowing you to debug the service with visual studio.